# How to specify to Travis to use a specific bundler which I have used on local development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, travis-ci

I am using Travis CI for continuous development on my application.

When I push to GitHub and gitignore my my `Gemfile.lock` from being pushed to GitHub, then Travis will work fine and install all dependencies, but when Travis (`.travis.yml`) is ready to push to Heroku, I get a [This Travis Build Error](https://travis-ci.org/AfolabiOlaoluwa/LawVille/builds/166271491)

**Picture of the error**

[image]

**Heroku Build Log Error**

[image]

I understand the error being its requiring the Gemfile.lock file to be pushed alongside the code, but if I push Gemfile.lock with the rest of the code to GitHub, my Travis will not build at all and will **throw Bundler Error being Gemlock file corrupt**. The only solution I did to solve that was to remove Gemfile.lock being pushed to GitHub.

> Having figured out my problem, how do I solve this by stating the
>   exact bundler I want my Travis to use, or is there any other thing I
>   could do to solve this?

**Travis (.travis.yml)**

```
language: ruby 
rvm:
- 2.2.4
env:
  global:
  - secure: {{ I have my travis encrypted key here }}
  - secure: {{ I another travis encrypted key here }}
  - DB=sqlite
  - DB=mysql
  - DB=postgresql
  - secure: {{ I have another travis encrypted key here }}
deploy:
 provider: heroku
 api_key:
   secure: {{ I have heroku api key encrypted key here }}
 app: lawville
 on:
   repo: AfolabiOlaoluwa/LawVille
script:
- RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
- bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
before_script:
- mysql -e 'create database strano_test'
- psql -c 'create database strano_test' -U postgres
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manipulated this by including `before_install script` in my `travis.yml`.

Here is the code:

```
before_install:
  - gem install -v 1.10.6 bundler --no-rdoc --no-ri
  - bundle _1.10.6_ install
```

With this script my travis file did as expected using bundler version I set in travis.